# Input boxes don't have a "hitbox" and appear in front of the text

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, css-position

I'm having issues creating my auto-completing/auto-suggesting input box.
This is how it's currently working: https://i.imgur.com/2RzI3il.gifv

And here's a code snippet, bare in mind, the react code isn't included. The functionality isn't important, just the CSS layout.

```css
.App {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: "Ubuntu", sans-serif;
}

#main{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  background: transparent;
}
#autocomplete{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: transparent;
  z-index: 0;
}

.LocationInput {
  position: relative;
  margin: 30px;
  font-size: 1.1em;
  font-family: "proxima-nova", Arial;
}

.LocationInput-Input {
  padding: 5px 5px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #002857;
  -webkit-transition: 0.5s;
}

.LocationInput-Input:focus {
  outline: none;
}

.LocationInput-Input-Valid {
  padding: 5px 5px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 1px solid rgb(107, 175, 19);
  -webkit-transition: 0.5s;
}

.LocationInput-Input-Valid:focus {
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="App" class="LocationInput LocationInput-from">
  <div>
    from:
    <input type="text" id="main"
           class="LocationInput-Input-Valid"
           value="Thórshavn">
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="text" id="autocomplete"
           class="LocationInput-Input"
           value="Thórshavn" disabled="">
  </div>
</div>
```

I want it to be displayed like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/X5LfT.png

However, it is being displayed like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YbWkF.png

When I use Chrome's inspect tool, I find that the elements have these weird "hitboxes": https://i.imgur.com/b923Dzp.gifv

though that might not be relevant? I've tried to fix this and I just suck at CSS too much :p

Comment: Some of the css in your example is missing. Please take the time to create a working example (jsfiddle/snippet/codepen) that shows exactly how your entire page looks like.

Comment: Absolute positioning removes the "hitbox" causing your problem.

Comment: @Dekel added code snippet, thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: @SamR well, I need the absolute positioning to have the two input boxes in the same place (overlap) right? How would I fix it?
(Also, see added code snippet)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways to work this out, here is one of them:

```css
.App {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: "Ubuntu", sans-serif;
}

.input-contianer {
  position: relative;
  text-align: left;
}
label {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 5px;
}
#main{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 60px;
  z-index: 1;
  background: transparent;
}
#autocomplete{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 60px;
  background: transparent;
  z-index: 0;
}

.LocationInput {
  position: relative;
  margin: 30px;
  font-size: 1.1em;
  font-family: "proxima-nova", Arial;
}

.LocationInput-Input {
  padding: 5px 5px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #002857;
  -webkit-transition: 0.5s;
}

.LocationInput-Input:focus {
  outline: none;
}

.LocationInput-Input-Valid {
  padding: 5px 5px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 1px solid rgb(107, 175, 19);
  -webkit-transition: 0.5s;
}

.LocationInput-Input-Valid:focus {
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="App" class="LocationInput LocationInput-from">
  <div class="input-contianer">
    <label>
    from:
    </label>
    <input type="text" id="main"
           class="LocationInput-Input-Valid"
           value="Thórshavn">
    <input type="text" id="autocomplete"
           class="LocationInput-Input"
           value="Thórshavn" disabled="">
  </div>
</div>
```

1. I kept the two inputs `absolute` positioned, but wrapped them in a `.input-container` div that has a `relative` position (so the `absolute` will be absolute to the `relative` container).
2. I added a `<label>` element that will wrap the `from:`, this way you can position that label.

Answer (score 1):

You should set a wrapping div with a relative position and play with the `left` position of the inputs

```css
.App {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: "Ubuntu", sans-serif;
}

.container{
  position:relative;
}

.label{
  position: absolute;
  padding: 5px;
}

#main {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50px;
  z-index: 1;
  background: transparent;
}

#autocomplete {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50px;
  background: transparent;
  z-index: 0;
}

.LocationInput {
  position: relative;
  margin: 30px;
  font-size: 1.1em;
  font-family: "proxima-nova", Arial;
}

.LocationInput-Input {
  padding: 5px 5px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #002857;
  -webkit-transition: 0.5s;
}

.LocationInput-Input:focus {
  outline: none;
}

.LocationInput-Input-Valid {
  padding: 5px 5px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 1px solid rgb(107, 175, 19);
  -webkit-transition: 0.5s;
}

.LocationInput-Input-Valid:focus {
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="App" class="LocationInput LocationInput-from">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="label">from:</div>
    <input type="text" id="main" class="LocationInput-Input-Valid" value="Thórshavn">
    <input type="text" id="autocomplete" class="LocationInput-Input" value="Thórshavn" disabled="">
  </div>
</div>
```